# L5973 (step down) used in constant current oscillates

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, constant-current, oscillation

For a couple of days i'am playing with a L5973 dc - dc converter whith I want to convert to a constant current driver for 5 or 10W LED's. It kind of works but I get some oscillations in audible range. I want the current to be controlled with PWM signal from microcontroller, but now i use a potentiometer to set volatage on PWM flag. I'm using LM358 opamp.

I also find this document, but they don't use opamps, so the current is controlled by resistor value, and i want to control it via PWM. Or maybe is there a way to add this feature there?
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/f3/ee/83/89/e2/53/4a/7a/CD00072891.pdf/files/CD00072891.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00072891.pdf

Here is the schematic: I can also post screenshot from oscilloscope if it will be helpful.

[image: schematic]

Thanks for replies and soryy for my english, I'm from Poland. :)

Answer (score 2):

Section 3 of your linked document is the classical approach to current regulating an LED because of its simplicity and, clear compliance with rules that govern the L5973 (and most other chips of this type) in order to keep the feedback loop stable.

One of those rules is don’t screw around with the feedback path and, in particular, don’t add op-amps into the feedback path unless you know the general consequences and are prepared to run the extra mile to ensure loop stability.

But, you are adding two series op-amp circuits into the feedback path so you have to take great care that the loop remains stable.

> It kind of works but I get some oscillations in audible range.

I smell a whiff of instability and that instability could damage your LEDs with over current quite easily.

An alternative to your approach is to go back to the classical way of connecting your LEDs as mentioned in section 3 but allow your PWM signal to modify what is fed back to the FB pin directly and passively.

For instance, you are already converting your PWM to an analogue voltage and, if this voltage is directly fed to the FB pin via a high (ish) resistance you can “con” the chip into shutting down current into the LEDs.

Comment: Tkanks for very comprehensive answer. Could You Please explain one more thing: I dont See output capacitor, so the current will not be stable but oscillate (250kHz is swiching frequency) I am thinking right? I will try Your idea tommorow and see how it works.

Comment: There should be an output cap but it wouldn’t need to be as big as one used on a regular dc to dc converter. Try looking through the linked document with a fine tooth comb is my advice. The reason you need one is that, without one, your feedback signal is messy.

Comment: @fifi_22 - did you sort this out? Have you finished with this Q and A now?

Comment: I didn't - it was fast project, so I just switched to MP2480 chip. However I will have some time now (this week) I can play with this and post something